# CakePHP 2.x Paginaton: Remember which page you're one

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, paginator

I'm working on a webshop. In the categories view we load the products in with jquery because the user is able to filter them. This works great.

We then tried to save the page the user was on (in the pagination), so that if he views a product and gets back to the categorie view, he starts on the page he was previously on. For example, I'm on pagination page 3, view a product, hit the browser back button, and continue on page 3 instead on 1 (which is default cakephp behaviour). We save the page number in a session, which works great as far as we can see. Then we read that pagenumber from the session and use it in our $this->paginate as 'page' => $pagenumber. This also works.

But there is one weird problem. When you start on page 2 or 3 (read: any page bigger than 1, but we only have 3 pages at the moment), you can't get back to page 1. Switching to page 2 or 3 works great, but you can't switch to page 1. If you click on it nothing happens, it does send a network request thingy in the chrome element inspector so something is happing in the background. If we manually set the page to 'page' => 1. It works, you can switch to all 3 pages.

I hope you understand my problem, I tried to explain it as best as I can. (Sorry if my English isn't too good, I tried the best I could).

My code (I made it as short as possible without fields en joins):
In the controller

```
$page_number = $this->Session->read('Pagination.currentpage');

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Product.status' => 'active',
        'Product.visibility' => 1,
        'Product.hidden_on_site' => 0,
    ),
    'order' => 'Product.name ASC',
    'limit' => 20,
    'recursive' => 2,
    'page' => $page_number,
);
```

The $page_number works, it outputs the right page. But it gives the problem that you can't get tot page 1 if you're on page 2 or 3. If we manually set 'page' => 1 it works.

I hope you have a clue or a solution that works in an other way...

Comment: I assume you are not clearing your session. because you are getting you page number from session. try to clear your session and rewrite the page_number

Comment: No, that's not working. I'm not exactly sure why it works, but if I comment out the part that in the pagination helper takes out page:1 of the url, it works.

Comment: Make sure that when the value of the Session read `Pagination.currentpage` is supposed to be an integer 1, it's not being interpreted as boolean `true` instead.

Comment: No the value is an int, but thanks for thinking along.

Comment: what happens if you omit the 'page' key => value pair completely?

Comment: It starts on the first page if that's what you meant?

Comment: isn't that the behaviour you want?

Comment: No, because then you always start at page 1. You need to start on the page you were previously on. Which is working, except if you want to go back to page 1. But it is working now, as you could see in my answer on Isaac.

Answer (score 0):

The CakePHP 2.x [PaginationRecall Component](http://abakalidis.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/cakephp-saving-paging-data-in-session.html) works very well for this purpose. I use it in several of my projects.

Author is SO member [Athanassios Bakalidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542990/thanassis).